# how to get uri req res body from a yaml by swagger parser

Tags: swagger

I want to get uri, request, response body, response code from a swagger yaml file.

Then I can put them into my own database.
Like this:

[image: my database]

I tried to do something by adding `io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser` in a java program. I think the way swagger codegen does it is the right solution. But I can't get anything from the source code of codegen.

---

This question is about parsing the yaml file and get the structure.
Next question: [How to get request body and response body in JSON from a Swagger yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185350/how-to-get-request-body-and-response-body-in-json-from-a-swagger-yaml)

Comment: Do not vandalize your question please

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use a parser to parse the specification file.
Then you can iterate over the elements you are interested in and do what ever you want.

If your specification input is in the Swagger `2.0` format (json or yaml), you can use this parser:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.34</version>
</dependency>
```

Here an example method:

```
import java.util.Map;

import io.swagger.models.HttpMethod;
import io.swagger.models.Operation;
import io.swagger.models.Path;
import io.swagger.models.Response;
import io.swagger.models.Swagger;
import io.swagger.models.parameters.Parameter;
import io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser;

public class UseParserExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Swagger swagger = new SwaggerParser().read("<path to your specification>");
    Map<String, Path> paths = swagger.getPaths();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Path> p : paths.entrySet()) {
      Path path = p.getValue();
      Map<HttpMethod, Operation> operations = path.getOperationMap();
      for (Entry<HttpMethod, Operation> o : operations.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("===");
        System.out.println("PATH:" + p.getKey());
        System.out.println("Http method:" + o.getKey());
        System.out.println("Summary:" + o.getValue().getSummary());
        System.out.println("Parameters number: " + o.getValue().getParameters().size());
        for (Parameter parameter : o.getValue().getParameters()) {
          System.out.println(" - " + parameter.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("Responses:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Response> r : o.getValue().getResponses().entrySet()) {
          System.out.println(" - " + r.getKey() + ": " + r.getValue().getDescription());
        }
        System.out.println("");
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Here an ouput example:

```
PATH: /user/{username}
Http method: PUT
Summary: Updated user
Parameters number: 2
 - username
 - body
Responses:
 - 400: Invalid user supplied
 - 404: User not found

===
PATH: /user/{username}
Http method: DELETE
Summary: Delete user
Parameters number: 1
 - username
Responses:
 - 400: Invalid username supplied
 - 404: User not found
```

Comment: This is an other question. I think there is some code to do this in swagger-codegen. Please ask an other question and add the link here.